# Writing specs for custom devise actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have an app that has a custom version of `Devise::RegistrationsController`. When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: post :create
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   Could not find devise mapping for path "/users".
   Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

       devise_scope :user do
         match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
       end
```

I don't get why I'm getting this error, since everything functions just fine from the user's perspective. Here's what I have in `routes/config.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :sign_up => 'signup'}
```

Any ideas? Is there something special I have to do when writing specs for Devise controllers?

Comment: have you added `RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are testing Devise controllers you need to specify the scope. It's as simple as:

```
before { @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user] }
```

Assuming User is the model you're trying to authenticate